# Configuring AIR for desktop as Facebook Application

Tags: facebook, air, desktop

Creating an AIR desktop application that has the ability to upload images to a Facebook user's account.
Even though this is a desktop application, in order to integrate with Facebook you need to embed a 'webview'. 
So I am confused as to how I should define this on Facebook? From Facebook's point of view, is this a web application or a desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/requirements#platforms:

> *“Desktop apps should submit a Web platform and include detailed screenshots or a screencast of the integration.”*

Choose a dummy address for the Website platform (such as `http://localhost/`), and mention the fact that this is not actually a website app, but a desktop app, very explicitly in your review instructions.

Comment: Thanks, so in the application settings for this app, I assume I choose Desktop?